# How to traverse all the members inside a jobject

Tags: java-native-interface

For example, I have a Java class:

```
public class JniTest {
    public int member_int_;
    public int member_int_2_;
    public boolean member_bool_;
    public static int member_static_int_ = 90;
    public String member_str_;
    void print() {};
}
```

in JNI, I want to get each member without knowing their names in advance:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_tencent_qqmail_protocol_JniMethodTest_TestObject(JNIEnv * env, jclass cls, jobject obj) {

    *for (each member in obj)* { ... } //how to implement ?

}
```

Comment: You might want to reconsider your architecture to do as much as possible on the Java side before transitioning to JNI.  This type of reflection is easy to do in Java, but error-prone in JNI and potentially requires crossing the JNI boundary (which I'd consider doing anyway unless there were some severe performance constraints).    Can you edit your question to provide more context into your broader goal?

Answer (score 1):

Starter : [Trail: The Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

1. Method getDeclaredMethods returns an array of Method objects, excluding inherited methods
2. Method getDeclaredFields returns an array of Field objects, excluding inherited fields
3. Method getSuperclass returns the super class

As @technomage commented, doing all the work in JNI is hard to do correctly (especially if you don't like memory leak and crash)

If you are not already "fluent" in JNI, start with simpler goals.